# Correct way to prevent CSRF in PHP? Current system doesn't work in certain browsers

Tags: html, forms, cookies, token, csrf

Currently I use a simple system in PHP to prevent CSRF on any forms on my website.

It's based on this: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/20015/protecting-against-csrf-when-a-form-is-being-submitted-via-an-ajax-call

I include this in all forms:

```
<?php
$token = md5(uniqid(mt_rand(), true));
setcookie("token", $token, 0, '/', ($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] != 'localhost') ? $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] : false);
?>

<input type="hidden" name="token" value="<?php echo($token); ?>" />
```

And this is all PHP that the form is submitted to:

```
if ((isset($_COOKIE['token'])) && ($_POST['token'] == $_COOKIE['token'])) {
    //Remove token and continue
} else {
    //Remove token and stop - fails check
}
```

So I've tested this on an Android phone, iPad, iPhone and several desktop browsers. It works on all browsers apart from the mobile version of Chrome and the default browser on Android phones. In these cases it fails the check every time - even when it shouldn't.

What exactly am I doing to cause these particular browsers to not work. I was under the impression that my system for blocking CSRF was standard?

Answer (score 1):

```
<input type="hidden" name="token" value="<?php xecho($token); ?>" />
```

should be:

```
<input type="hidden" name="token" value="<?php echo $token; ?>" />
```

or simply:

```
<input type="hidden" name="token" value="<?=$token;?>" />
```

Comment: Are you sure that cookies are enabled on the mobile devices you tested on? Be sure to verify whether or not the cookies are actually being set. After your setcookie call - do print_r($_COOKIE) and make sure `token` exists.

Comment: I personally haven't heard of that. Although, I typically work with $_SESSION for tokens, and not $_COOKIE. Worth looking into further.